# Pass Node.js environment variable with Windows PowerShell

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell

I'm trying pass an environment variable to Node.js with PowerShell like this way:

```
C:\Users\everton\my-project> $env:MY_VAR = 8000 node index.js
```

But I get an error in PowerShell:

> Token 'node' unexpected expression or statement

Comment: You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509175/11127383

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Set environmental variable `MY_VAR` first and run your app like this:

```
C:\Users\everton\my-project> $env:MY_VAR="8000" ; node index.js
```

You can access environmental variable `MY_VAR` inside `index.js` by

```
process.env.MY_VAR
```

Note: PowerShell doesn't directly support command-scoped environment variables. The above command sets the environment variable for that PowerShell session.

Comment: This sets the command for the whole "bash" session, this is not command scoped

Comment: Indeed and that's worth mentionning. Also worth mentionning my previous comment. Imagine somebody coming here to look for a solution on a production environment. He runs your command to troubleshoot an incident and run his command with `NODE_ENV=dev` to get node.js tracing. He fixes the trouble then he restarts his server with `node index.js`. Except he doesn't know he's still in `NODE_ENV=dev` and added 500ms latency on every page view on his website. The reasonnable answer is "PowerShell can't do that, use the right tool or workaround like this"

Answer (score 9):

My answer require the use of Node.js and npm libraries.

...or you just take out the pain of writing obscure-WTF-language-scripting, and use one of command-scoped (plus cross-platform) Node.js scripts:

- [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) (for inline)

  ```
  cross-env MYVAR=MYVALUE node index.js
  ```
- [`env-cmd`](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) (from .env file)

  ```
  env-cmd .env node index.js
  ```

  with

  ```
  #.env file
  MYVAR=MYVALUE
  ```

Answer (score 8):

<sup>Note: If you can assume that *Node.js* is already installed - as is by definition the case when you're invoking `node` - consider use of `npm` helper packages, as shown in [Cyril CHAPON 's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342374/45375).

*This* answer focuses on *generic solutions* from within PowerShell.</sup>

**tl;dr**

```sh
# Set env. variable temporarily, invoke the external utility, 
# then remove / restore old value.
$oldVal, $env:MYVAR = $env:MYVAR, 8000; node index.js; $env:MYVAR = $oldVal
```

```sh
# Scoped alternative that uses a *transient* helper variable.
& { $oldVal, $env:MY_VAR = $env:MY_VAR, 8000; node index.js; $env:MY_VAR = $oldVal }
```

More simply, if there's no preexisting `MY_VAR` value that must be restored.

```sh
$env:MYVAR=8000; node index.js; $env:MYVAR=$null
```

See below for an explanation and an alternative based on a helper function.

---

To complement [Harikrishnan's effective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43025189/45375):

**PowerShell has *no* equivalent to the *command-scoped* method of passing environment variables that POSIX-like shells offer** (as of PowerShell v7 - however, introducing it to PowerShell - not necessarily with the same syntax - is being discussed in [GitHub issue #3316](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3316)); e.g.:

```sh
 # E.g., in *Bash*: 
 # Define environment variable MY_VAR for the child process being invoked (`node`)
 # ONLY; in other words: MY_VAR is scoped to the command being invoked
 # (subsequent commands do not see it).
 MY_VAR=8000 node index.js
```

In PowerShell, as Harikrishnan's answer demonstrates, **you have to define the environment variable *first*, and then, in a *separate statement*, call the external program**, so `$env:MY_VAR="8000"; node index.js` *is* the right PowerShell solution, but it is worth nothing that **`$env:MY_VAR` *stays in scope*** for the **remainder of the *session*** (it is set at the ***process* level**).

Note that even using a script block invoked with `&` to create a child scope doesn't help here, because such child scopes only apply to *PowerShell* variables, not *environment* variables.

You can, of course, **remove the environment variable *manually after* the `node` call**:
`Remove-Item env:MY_VAR` or even just `$env:MY_VAR = $null`, which is what the 1st command at the top shows.

---

A **more structured alternative** - perhaps better in the case of setting *multiple* environment variables and/or invoking multiple commands - is to use a script block invoked with `&`:

```sh
& { $oldVal, $env:MY_VAR = $env:MY_VAR, 8000; node index.js; $env:MY_VAR = $oldVal }
```

This takes advantage of:

- `{ ... }` is a script block that provides a clearly visible grouping for the commands in it; invoked with `&`, it creates a local scope, so that helper variable `$oldVal` automatically goes out of scope on exiting the block.
- `$oldVal, $env:MY_VAR = $env:MY_VAR, 8000` saves the old value (if any) of `$env:MY_VAR` in `$oldVal` while changing the value to `8000`; this technique of assigning to multiple variables at once (known as *destructuring assignment* in some languages) is explained in [`Get-Help about_Assignment_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators), section "ASSIGNING MULTIPLE VARIALBES".

**Alternatively**, use the **helper function below**, or use a **`try { ... } finally { ... }`** approach, as demonstrated in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435332/45375).

---

#### Helper function for command-scoped environment modifications.

If you define the helper function below (remember that function definitions must be placed *before* they're invoked), you can achieve command-scoped modification of your environment as follows:

```sh
# Invoke `node index.js` with a *temporarily* set MY_VAR environment variable.
Invoke-WithEnvironment @{ MY_VAR = 8000 } { node index.js }
```

`Invoke-WithEnvironment()` **source code**:

```sh
function Invoke-WithEnvironment {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Invokes commands with a temporarily modified environment.

.DESCRIPTION
Modifies environment variables temporarily based on a hashtable of values,
invokes the specified script block, then restores the previous environment.

.PARAMETER Environment
A hashtable that defines the temporary environment-variable values.
Assign $null to (temporarily) remove an environment variable that is
currently set.

.PARAMETER ScriptBlock
The command(s) to execute with the temporarily modified environment.

.EXAMPLE
> Invoke-WithEnvironment @{ PORT=8080 } { node index.js }

Runs node with environment variable PORT temporarily set to 8080, with its
previous value, if any 
#>
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [System.Collections.IDictionary] $Environment,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
  )
  # Modify the environment based on the hashtable and save the original 
  # one for later restoration.
  $htOrgEnv = @{}
  foreach ($kv in $Environment.GetEnumerator()) {
    $htOrgEnv[$kv.Key] = (Get-Item -EA SilentlyContinue "env:$($kv.Key)").Value
    Set-Item "env:$($kv.Key)" $kv.Value
  }
  # Invoke the script block
  try {
    & $ScriptBlock
  } finally {
    # Restore the original environment.
    foreach ($kv in $Environment.GetEnumerator()) {
      # Note: setting an environment var. to $null or '' *removes* it.
      Set-Item "env:$($kv.Key)" $htOrgEnv[$kv.Key]
    }
  }
}
```