# Power-shell /Windows equivalent of bash script

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, windows-10, sh

I'm trying to do the following simple command in `Windows 10` via Power-Shell CLI. How can I do that?

```
ID=test001 ./initializeID.sh
```

Where `initializeID.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Initializing for ID: $ID"
DPPROG="{\"title\":\"Test \", \"Id\": \"$ID\"}"
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "$DPPROG" http://localhost:8080/StorageApi/id
```

Currently if I run it, it shows this error:

```
ID=test001 : The term 'ID=test001' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ID=test001 ./initializeID.sh
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ID=test001:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Keep in mind you're not going to be able to just run a `.sh` script in Powershell. The shebang also isn't a thing in Windows either.

Comment: Please see the linked post and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030126/45375) for details.

Comment: Good point, @BendertheGreatest. Tina J, the syntax you're using only works in POSIX-like shells such as Bash. In PowerShell, `ID=test001` is being interpreted as the _name of command_, which explains the error message. If you also need to translate the script itself: look at `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Invoke-WebRequest` for `curl`-like functionality.

Comment: Even in linux I had problems running that. `./initializeID.sh` needs permission and cannot run without `bash`. But Idk how to pass the `ID=test001` then.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this directly. You could set the variable and then run the command like so:

```
$env:VARIABLE = 'somevalue'; some-command-or-script
```

but this will persist the envvar in the current powershell session that invoked `some-command-or-script`. You would need to either run `Remove-Item ENV:VARIABLE` after `some-command-or-script` exits or store off the original value before the line above, and restore it after the command completes.

Comment: Even in linux I had problems running that. `./initializeID.sh` needs permission and cannot run without `bash`. But Idk how to pass the `ID=test001` then. Is there any workaround for that?