# Need to pass AWS secret (environment variable) from powershell to Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, powershell, aws-secrets-manager, aws-powershell

I have an environment variable in PowerShell
`$env.aws_password`
and this holds the aws password and I need to pass this environment variable to javascript.

I am running the javascript file using
`& '\path\to\ScriptRunner.exe' '\path\to\CognosGroupsExtract.js'`

And in the Javscript file i am passing the environment variable
`var password = "process.env.aws_password"`

`server.logon("username",password)`

I am getting reference error as process is not defined and cannot install node.
I cannot install anything in javascript and i have to pass password through memory. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

See: [Pass Node.js environment variable with Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024906/pass-node-js-environment-variable-with-windows-powershell)

`process.env` is specific to Node.js, you would need to pass the password through memory.

```
& '\path\to\ScriptRunner.exe' '\path\to\CognosGroupsExtract.js' $env:aws_password
```

Please try this and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Will try out this way. But how do I define it in javascript?

Comment: No this is not working. I tried it but it creates a new environment